# Did Rashi wear a yarmulke?

Tags: history, rashi, kippa-yarmulka

[Tractate Sofrim (14:14)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20355&st=&pgnum=61) records two opinions that concern the wearing of a head covering during the Shema: there are those who say that it is not necessary, and there are those who say that it *is* necessary, since one whose head is uncovered may not pronounce the name of God. According to the Bet Yosef (Tur, OC 91:3), the halakha is in accordance with the latter opinion (that a head covering must be worn), since that was the opinion codified by Rabbeinu Yerucham (Sefer Toldot 16:7, 148d).

Interestingly, the [Darkhei Moshe (Tur, OC 282:1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37205&st=&pgnum=84&hilite=) records the fact that there was a French custom to follow the *other* opinion, and not to wear a head covering when reading Torah. His source for this is the [Or Zarua, which notes ([II:43])](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8727&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=) that this was not merely a local custom, but something that the *Rabbonim* in France were doing.

The gradual stabilisation of the custom of wearing a head covering all day long was at times a controversial subject ([with yarmulkes occasionally being drawn onto the heads of rabbis in drawings](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%204%20Rabinowitz.pdf)), but the image of bareheaded men reading Torah or reciting Shema is striking.

To which rabbonim in France was the Or Zarua referring? Did *Rashi* wear a yarmulke? Did he ever discuss the obligation to do so in his responsa?

Comment: [This 16th Century wood cut](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rashi_woodcut.jpg) assumes he did.

Comment: There is a joke that Parshas Vayaitzai is the proof of wearing a yarmulke. It starts "and Yaakov went out". Would any tzadik go out without his yarmulkeh?  (Leftover Purim reaction).

Comment: I find this question repulsive. How dare you cast doubt as to whether Rashi wore a Yarmulke? I know that the editors that know better than me will nuke me for my comment, however I have to protest.

Comment: @GershonGold, I agree that the title is unnecessarily provocative, but Rashi could have worn an early form of a [Chaperon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaperon_(headgear)) instead.

Comment: @Yishai: Then the question should be "What type of headcovering did Rashi wear?" not "Did Rashi wear a yarmulke?"

Comment: The Darkhei Moshe is refering exclusively to allowing children to read from the Torah (as that is all the Or Zarua talks about). The Or Zarua itself *may* be saying that the adults said a blessing without a head covering, but it is very clear that the adults read from the Torah in shul with their heads covered, but allowed children to have an alliah on Simchas Torah without covering their heads. So the children, then didn't universally cover until an older age. Drawing conclusions about adults is highly speculative.

Comment: @GershonGold [Is your initial comment serious?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law)